# Blazor .net core ref enum? param not changing its value

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

Im a bit confused with whats happening bellow:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain me why is dataType keep saying StatisticData instead of SibsMonthly??

dataType is a enum? passad as ref param to this method and its initialized as null before the method call..

Here is the code:

```
string errorMessage = null;
Enums.Uploads.DataType? dataType = null;

if (ValidadeFile(file, ref errorMessage, ref dataType))
{
    ...
}
 
private bool ValidadeFile(IBrowserFile file, ref string errorMessage, ref Enums.Uploads.DataType? dataType)
{
    List<string> acceptedFileTypes = new List<string>
    {
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    };
    var valid = true;

    if (AcceptedFileNames != null && AcceptedFileNames.Length > 0)
    {
        var tmp = AcceptedFileNames.Where(x => new Regex(x.Regex).IsMatch(file.Name))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DataType)
            .Select(x => x.DataType)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        dataType = tmp;

        if (dataType == null)
        {
            valid = false;
            errorMessage = Constants.Uploads.Error.InvalidFileName;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you debugging the code that's running? Or are there other threads modifying that member?

Comment: Im debuging the code, no other threads are running.. and by the way im using ref for dataType and its nullable so its initialized before the method call as null

Comment: @BrianParker I know the regex expression, as you can read in the code its inside of x.Regex....

Comment: @Brian the entire point is that `dataType = tmp` doesn't appear to update the variable `dataType`. Linq is not relevant here, OP calls `var tmp = ...FirstOrDefault()`, so the query for obtaining `tmp` is not evaluated again or something like that.

Comment: Guys I believe its a VS Debugger bug for the Blazor part of the code, because when it reaches the api the value is updated.. Should I Delete this question? or let it here in case of someone ends up with the same problem?

Comment: Please post the whole method and the Enum code in the Question.  Also are the two screen shots from exactly the same point in the code on the same run.   It's hard to answer a problem with so little information.  While not impossible, it's unlikely to be a Debugger bug.

Comment: Yes the screen shots are exactly from the same point in the code on the same run at the same moment, I will add the extra info to the code..

Comment: Can you set dataType as a out value rather than a ref?  Without seeing the code around ref `Enums.Uploads.DataType? dataType` and the enum definition itself ???

Comment: If it's a bug, please report it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WASM debugger doesn't seem to like `ref` variables, it seems to look at their address, not their value:

[image: Enum]

[image: String]

Inspecting them at their call site or in the Debug window behaves as expected; this is a debugger isssue.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster, Realised it and we could all report it to Microsoft, the more we report the better the chances we have to make them fix it.